# Is there a way to override an outer level of CSS?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

So in my application.html.erb I have a basic format for my entire web page

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body
```

and on only one of my pages I want to override the width attribute. Is there any way in my index.html.erb page that I can override the upper level CSS `"container"`? Or would I have to change my application.html.erb?

Comment: NO. CSS attributes can't be changed willy-nilly. Once you set the `max-width` of `p` tags on one page, they will be that width for the remainder of your days. Unless you go "off the grid" for a while and wear a false mustache. You might be able to trick the browser then.

Comment: ...Or I suppose you could just use a more specific selector by putting the body of that special page in a class, say `class="skinny"` and then in your CSS you'd have `body.skinny { width: 2em; }`. But such an act would tear down the thin veneer of civility which separates man from beast, and serve as the canonical example of a grotesque affront to the natural order.

Comment: To be rigorously exact, you'd do `<div class="container thinksItsSpecial">` and the CSS would be `div.container.thinksItsSpecial { width: 1in; }`. Or you could add an id to drive home the point (not recommended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you just need to add some identifiers in your markup, i.e. something like

```erb
<!-- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb -->
<body class="<%= body_classes %>">
  <div class="container">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

and define the helper like so:

```rb
# app/helpers/layout_helper.rb
module LayoutHelper
  def body_classes
    "controller-#{controller_name} action-#{action_name}"
  end
end
```

and finally define your CSS:

```css
/* app/assets/stylesheets/application.css */
.container {
  width: 80em;
}
body.controller-foo.action-show .container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

`controller-foo`/`action-show` implies the desired view, in this example `FooController#show`.

---

**Alternatively**, you could create a seperate layout, e.g. `app/views/layouts/wide.html.erb`:

```erb
<body>
  <div class="container wide">
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
</body>
```

```css
/* app/assets/stylesheets/application.css */
.container {
  width: 80em;
}
.container.wide {
  width: 100%;
}
```

and use this in your controller:

```rb
# app/controllers/foo_controller.rb
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render layout: 'wide'
  end
end
```